# What is the difference between Abstraction and Inheritance?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, abstraction

I could not find this question anywhere. Based upon my understanding, Inheritance should/might be the subset of Abstraction.

Comment: Abstraction in the first case and Abstract in the second refer to different concepts.
the first refer to a "concept" in programming, the second is a particular kind of class with specific properties, So "abstraction vs Inherithance is a question with little or no meaning.

Comment: @GianPaolo am looking for the difference between the two concepts. Why it has little or no meaning?

Comment: A raw (and quite bad) example: it's like if you are asking _I can find question about the difference between "live" an "die", and betweeen "living room" and "dining room", but I don't understand the difference between "live" and "dining room"_ 
(sorry, English is not my mother tongue language, could not find a more fitting example)

Comment: @GianPaolo that's funny but not valid (Abstraction and Inheritance both are oops concepts just like living and dinning room)

Comment: my previous comment refers to the previous version of the question

Comment: @GianPaolo ok, what about this version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of you should be aware, that here is always some leeway in interpreting such terms and concepts. Below is my take on it.

Abstraction is the concept while inheritance is a technical realization.

---

Abstraction in general refers to the leaving out of (unnecessary) details. The opposite direction is concretization. Generalization is also often used in this context and basically means the same as abstraction.

In the context of computer science this can be used to describe several ideas:

- One is the modelling of domain concepts. As in `the class Car is an abstraction of real world automobiles. It uses an engine and four wheels to transport 1-5 people.` Obviously this is nowhere near the informational density to describe a real car, but it may very well be all that is needed for the context of this application.
- An other is to use it to describe the conceptual relation between multiple domain entities: `A Car is a Motorvehicle. A Bus is also a Motorvehicle. Both are used to transport people.` The Motorvehicle is the abstraction of both Car and Bus. It describes the idea of transporting people, while leaving out the detail of how many.
- A third is the difference between an interface and an implementation. The interface abstracts the implementation by hiding the implementation details and only representing the surface area with which one may interact.

---

Inheritance is one method of realizing abstractions in code. It describes the process of taking a base class (this is the more general or abstract thing), inheriting all of its features/properties/behavior/meaning and adding some more details (or overriding some of the existing) to create the derived class (this is the more concrete thing).

Answer (score 0):

First, When you mark a class as abstract you cannot create an instance. Abstract classes are used to be inherited only.

But when you inherited from a non abstract class you can create instance from both of derived and base classes. So you can say abstract classes are used to generate new types, to be inherited not to create instance !

This is also somehow related polymorphism.

For example you have a base Employee class like below:
public class Employee

```
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Salary { get; set; }

    public void IncreaseSalary(double rate)
    {
        this.Salary += (this.Salary * rate / 100);
    }
}
```

Now when we create SalesRepresentative class like below we should inherit it from Employee because SalesRepresentative is an Employee.

```
public class SalesRepresentative : Employee

    {
        public double AnnualSalesAmount { get; set; }
    }
```

Now `SalesRepresentative` object has `IncreaseSalary` method because it is inherited from Employee. But in generally Sales Representatives' and Employee's Salaries are increased by different ways for example according to their AnnualSalesAmount.

In this case you should be able to change method code of IncreaseSalary from SalesRepresentative but you can't. Actually now you are across with Polymorphism

Now Let's come to abstraction. If you want to change the default code of IncreaseSalary from inherited class there are 2 choices. First marking the method as Virtual. And the second one is marking it as abstract.

The difference is If you mark it as virtual. You don't have to implement it in `SalesRepresentative` but If you mark it as abstract you have to implement it and you should forget an abstract member can only be in abstract classes. Examine the example below:

```
public abstract class Employee

{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public double Salary { get; set; }

   public abstract void IncreaseSalary(double rate);

}
```

```
public class SalesRepresentative : Employee

    {
        public double AnnualSalesAmount { get; set; }

        public override void IncreaseSalary(double rate)
        {
            if (this.AnnualSalesAmount > 100000)
            {
                this.Salary += (this.Salary * (rate + 5) / 100);

            }
            else
            {
                this.Salary += (this.Salary * rate / 100);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, are you saying that if I inherit from base class (which is not abstract), then it is not abstraction.

Comment: When you inherited from a non abstract class you can create instance from both of derived and base classes. So also you can say abstract classes are used to generate new types, to be inherited not to create instance .

Comment: Also,  Every abstract class is a base class. It must be so, because the functions which are not defined inside the abstract class, must be defined in the derived classes. ... Only if interfaces are used then the class can implement more than one base class.

Comment: That's okay, but what is the difference between inheritance and abstraction?

Comment: Buddy thats the difference only above in which example is there as well have you read that completely difference there only and the basic difference is this: Inheritance and Abstraction: A Java interface can be implemented using keyword “implements” and abstract class can be extended using keyword “extends”. Multiple implementation: An interface can extend another Java interface only, an abstract class can extend another Java class and implement multiple Java interfaces.

Comment: I have asked for the conceptual difference. Is inheritance the subset of abstraction or not, something like that. You are not answering my question bro.

Comment: See, Inheritance is when one class aquire properties of another like child class aquire the properties of parent class and as abstract class is abstract hence Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed so you can it is the subset but not in a complete way.

Comment: It seems that you are misunderstanding my problem, I haven't asked the difference between abstract class and base class.